# Fatal Exception when writing to socket from another thread

Tags: android

I have set up a socket connection between two droids, and I can send data back and forth with no problem. However, in the server side I have set up a `ContentObserver` to be notified when there is a change to the contacts.

I get the notification, but when I try to send a message to the client that the contacts have changed, I get a fatal exception. The content observer code is

```
public class ContactWatcher extends ContentObserver {
   public ContactWatcher( Handler h ) 
   {
      super( h );
   }
   public void onChange(boolean selfChange) 
   { 
   if(!ConnectionManager.devices[0].matches("Null"))
   {
     ConnectionManager.sendMessage(MessageNames.CONTACT_UPDATE, 0);
   }
}
```

I get to the `sendMessage` code, but when it tries to write to the socket the program crashes with the LogCat output

```
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.write(BlockGuard.java:290)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:462)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:55)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:165)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:129)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at java.io.PrintWriter.flush(PrintWriter.java:270)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:491)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:603)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at com.gigaset.homepanel.ConnectionManager.sendMessage(ConnectionManager.java:151)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at com.gigaset.homepanel.ContactWatcher.onChange(ContactWatcher.java:19)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at android.database.ContentObserver$NotificationRunnable.run(ContentObserver.java:43)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
09-04 16:00:50.880: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(958):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android SDK documentation for the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` class is pretty clear and easy to understand. It states that it is thrown on Honeycomb when you try to perform a network operation on the main UI thread.

The fix is of course to run the network operation in a background thread. You can associate the `ContentObserver` with a different thread by passing a handler for that thread when you construct the `ContentObserver`.

Alternately, you could directly spawn a new thread, or post a runnable to a handler on a different thread.

If you really want to run the network operation on the main thread, you should be able to disable that exception via the `StrictMode` apis (not recommended)

Comment: You'll have to excuse the newbie here, but I thought that was what I was doing. In the main thread I have:                                             public Handler cHandler = new Handler();
public ContactWatcher cWatcher = null;                              ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
cWatcher = new ContactWatcher(cHandler);
cr.registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, cWatcher);     I thought the documentation stated that it would use that handler to run the onChange on a new thread.

Comment: When you create a new handler, it is associated with the thread that it is created on. In this case, you're creating the handler on the main thread, so it is associated with the main thread. Your best bet is probably to create and start an `AsyncTask` in your `ContentObserver`. Alternatively, you could run your own looper thread (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html), and pass in a `Handler` for that thread to the `ContentObserver`

Comment: That's where my confusion was. Thanks!